# Change pandas column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I have a pandas DataFrame that contains looks like this:

```
A         A_type
"Hello"   String
15        Integer
"Hi"      String
56.78     Float
```

I want to create a third column that reports the same value as A if A has the corresponding "A_type" element named "String", print "blank" otherwise. The column would look like:

```
B
"Hello"
"blank"
"Hi"
"blank"
```

I tried doing something like:

```
df['B'] = df['A']
for j in df['A_type']:
    for i in df['B']:
            if j == "String":
                i = i
            else:
                i = "blank"
```

Is there any more effective approach to such problem that can help me avoid all these for loops?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) or 
[`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with inverted condition, or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['B'] = df['A'].where(df['A_type'] == "String", 'blank')
#df['B'] = df['A'].mask(df['A_type'] != "String", 'blank')
#alternative
#df['B'] = np.where(df['A_type'] == "String", df['A'], 'blank')
print (df)
       A   A_type      B
0  Hello   String  Hello
1     15  Integer  blank
2     Hi   String     Hi
3  56.78    Float  blank
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try:

```
df['B'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['A'] if x['A_type'] == 'String' else "Blank", axis = 1)
```

Comment: Dont use apply, because loops under the hood, especially if exist vectorized alternatives.

Comment: Because it is slow in large dataframes

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I'll try to modify making it consistent with large df.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['B']=df['A'].copy()
df.loc[df['A_type']!="String", 'B'] = "blank"
```

O/P:

```
       A  A_type      B
0  Hello  String  Hello
1  blank   blank  blank
2     Hi  String     Hi
3  blank   blank  blank
```

explanation:

1. Take a copy of `Col A`
2. only update the value to `blank` where `A_Type` is not `String`

Comment: @DebanjanB - Added, thanks for the comment, I would consider this in futurte :)